# isn't showing product of Wishlist after login in laravel 8

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

**when i login amd add product to wishlist  there the products isn't appear in view wishlist page**
**where should i look at it in which file because everything's theeme looks correct for me but stil got same error**

**the problem**
[image]

**wishlist table**
[image]

**wishlist route**
//wishlist page

```
 Route::get('/wishlist', [WishlistController::class, 'ViewWishlist'])->name('wishlist');
     
    Route::get('/get-wishlist-product', [WishlistController::class, 'GetWishlistProduct']);
```

**wishlist controller**

```
public function ViewWishlist(){
        return view('frontend.wishlist.view_wishlist');
    }
 
    public function GetWishlistProduct(){
 
        $wishlist = Wishlist::with('product')->where('user_id',Auth::id())->latest()->get();
        return response()->json($wishlist);
    } // end mehtod
```

**view_wishlist page**

```
@extends('frontend.main_master')
@section('content')
 
@section('title')
 Wish List Page 
@endsection
 
 
<div class="breadcrumb">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="breadcrumb-inner">
            <ul class="list-inline list-unstyled">
                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                <li class='active'>Wishlist</li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.breadcrumb-inner -->
    </div><!-- /.container -->
</div><!-- /.breadcrumb -->
 
<div class="body-content">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="my-wishlist-page">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-12 my-wishlist">
    <div class="table-responsive">
        <table class="table">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th colspan="4" class="heading-title">My Wishlist</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody id="wishlist">
                
                 
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>          </div><!-- /.row -->
        </div><!-- /.sigin-in-->
<br>
 @include('frontend.body.brands')
</div>
 
@endsection
```

**wishlist script**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     function wishlist(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            url: '/user/get-wishlist-product',
            dataType:'json',
            success:function(response){
 
                var rows = ""
                $.each(response, function(key,value){
                    rows += `<tr>
                    <td class="col-md-2"><img src="/${value.product.product_thambnail} " alt="imga"></td>
                    <td class="col-md-7">
                        <div class="product-name"><a href="#">${value.product.product_name_en}</a></div>
                         
                        <div class="price">
                        ${value.product.discount_price == null
                            ? `${value.product.selling_price}`
                            :
                            `${value.product.discount_price} <span>${value.product.selling_price}</span>`
                        }
 
                            
                        </div>
                    </td>
        <td class="col-md-2">
            <button class="btn btn-primary icon" type="button" title="Add Cart" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" id="${value.product_id}" onclick="productView(this.id)"> Add to Cart </button>
        </td>
        <td class="col-md-1 close-btn">
            <button type="submit" class="" id="${value.id}" onclick="wishlistRemove(this.id)"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
        </td>
                </tr>`
        });
                
                $('#wishlist').html(rows);
            }
        })
 
     }
 wishlist();
 
 </script>
```

**wishlist model**

```
class Wishlist extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;
    protected $guarded = [];
 
 
    public function product(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Product::class,'product_id','id');
    }
 
}
```

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Also, please do not use irrelevant tags - or explain how the given problem is related to [tag:composer-php]  or [tag:migration]

Comment: @NicoHaase i have edited the tags and may if you help me by download  the project from github [link](https://github.com/AlaaEldin123/AdvanceEcommerceProject)  may you will got my probem